# MySQL - Mutual exclusion in transactions and locks?

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, transactions, acid

I am currently learning about MySQL's transaction and lock features.

Are transactions with the isolation-level `SERIALIZABLE` and statements between a `LOCK` and `UNLOCK` statement on the same table executed mutually exclusive?

---

**EDIT 1**: For the transaction thing with isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`, is it even possible to determine whether the transaction is actually mutually exclusive or just the requirements like no phantom reads are fulfilled? Or do these two properties imply the same behavior?

---

**EDIT 2**: Oh, and are the mechanisms that provide the given isolation-level of a transaction only active if two or more transactions actually work on the same data so that the read phenomena could actually happen?

Answer (score 1):

In InnoDB, all SERIALIZABLE does is turn a `SELECT` into an implicit `SELECT...LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. So this only affects INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE against the same row(s).

You can observe the locks in SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS:

```
---TRANSACTION 14594, ACTIVE 5 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 8 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 24, OS thread handle 0x7f65c8624700, query id 324 192.168.56.1 root cleaning up
TABLE LOCK table `imdb`.`kind_type` trx id 14594 lock mode IS
RECORD LOCKS space id 24 page no 4 n bits 80 index `kind` of table `imdb`.`kind_type` trx id 14594 lock mode S
```

All I did was `SELECT * FROM imdb.kind_type` after setting tx_isolation=SERIALIZABLE and autcommit=0.

You see that it holds an IS table lock, which will block a `LOCK TABLES kind_type WRITE`.

But if you're executing the transaction autocommit mode, it doesn't even do that; it just acts like REPEATABLE-READ.

Comment: What about causality in isolated transactions? If one transaction does something with the data and another session does so too, but without being in a transaction, are the read-phenomena requirements still met?

Comment: Everything in InnoDB is in a transaction, whether you begin/commit one explicitly or you rely on autocommit. In both cases, they will obey transaction isolation.